# Entity Framework for oracle 12c with nvarchar > 2000 code first

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC5 application with EF6. The application targets SQL Server 2014.

Our SQL Server database is ready and we have used Entity framework code first from Database to generate the EF entities to work with.

Now we are trying to make the application work on both SQL SERVER and ORACLE 12c. So we migrated our database to Oracle and switched our connection string to point to oracle.

Ideally EF should be supporting the two databases as we are using same schema on both databases.

However, I encountered few issues related to data types and sizes which EF is not allowing on Oracle. Some of them are:

1. NVARCHAR2 with length > 2000 is not supported for oracle ( however 12C supports it now).
2. Datatypes xml and ntext etc are not supported.

Please provide a resolution for the above issues as we do not want to maintain different EF for two databases.

regards,
A

Comment: Why do you use `NVARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR2`. Nowadays with Unicode and UTF-8 there is actually no need for NVARCHAR2 anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But my problem here the way EF treats the column data types. code first generates the entity with column length = 4000. When we try to use the same generated entities for Oracle we get error.

Comment: Have you found a solution? @WernfriedDomscheit how can I choose to generate VARCHAR2 instead of NVARCHAR2?

Comment: @sinsedrix, actually I don't think you can do that. Actually `VARCHAR2/NVARCHAR2` defines how the string are internally stored in Oracle rather than how strings are sent/received to/from database.